# Getting error in the location manager

Tags: java, android, locationmanager

I am trying to find out current latitude and longitude of android device but I am getting java.lang.nullpointerexception and app is force closing.even though i get refrence from here and used the code from the answer which was accepted as correct:
[How to get Android GPS location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498450/how-to-get-android-gps-location)
my code is:

```
try{
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
             Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
             String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
             Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);


        double latit=location.getLatitude();
        double longit=location.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your Location is:\nLatitude:\t"+latit+"\nLongitude:\t"+longit,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error:"+ex,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Comment: please paste error log..

Comment: I am sorry but my device is showing unsupported so i exported the apk.

Comment: yes device gps,data everything is on.Still its not working.I m getting nullpointer exception.Included permissions also

Comment: you can use gps tracker class to get current lat-long

Comment: refer http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that your `location` variable is null and that's why you're getting the `NullPointerException`.  When you call `LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation()` it can return null if there is no last known location.  Your best bet is to request location updates using one of the `LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates()` methods and passing in a `LocationListener`.

Comment: I have never used this method.please show me how to use this.

Comment: The best example that I could recommend come from Reto Meier's blog.  http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html