# Android 4.4.2 - Get Device Location Coordinates

Tags: java, android, mobile, gps

I'm using android 4.4.2 and I'm trying to get the device location coordinates without success.

This is the code I'm using :

**On Manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

**On class:**

```
   private double[] getLastBestLocation() {
            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);  
            List<String> providers = lm.getProviders(true);

            /* Loop over the array backwards, and if you get an accurate location, then break out the loop*/
            Location l = null;

            for (int i=providers.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
                    l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(i));
                    if (l != null) break;
            }

            double[] gps = new double[2];
            if (l != null) {
                    gps[0] = l.getLatitude();
                    gps[1] = l.getLongitude();
            }
            return gps;
    }
```

I've tried different answers provided at SO, specifically:

[How do I get the current GPS location programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android)
[How to get Android GPS location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498450/how-to-get-android-gps-location)

Please don't mark this question as duplicated since other answers didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This code uses both GPS as well as network for finding location.

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

// getting GPS status
isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

if (isGPSEnabled) {
    if (location == null) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this, null);
        if (locationManager != null) {
             location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();

            return location;
            }
        }
    }
}
// getting network status
isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

if (isNetworkEnabled) {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this, null);
    Log.v("Network", "Network is enabled");
    if (locationManager != null) {
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null) {                         
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            Log.v("LocationTracker", "Location : "+latitude+", "+longitude);
        }
        else
        {
                Log.v("LocationTracker", "Location is null");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Log.v("LocationTracker","Location manager is null");
    }
}
```