# Putting GPS-coordinates in a variable

Tags: java, android, gps, location

I have an application, in which I want to send my actual coordinates through email.

The code for opening a email client is the following:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

          //Funktion aufrufen, aber ausserhalb definieren

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        //i.setType("message/rfc822");
        i.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"mymail@example.com"});
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email";
        try {
            startActivity(i);
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
});
```

The `button` like this works fine.

Now I thought that I can define two variables with the actual `latitude` and the other with the current `longitude`.

For this purpose, I would have to get the actual coordinates.

So my question is: how can I put my current **GPS** coordinates in an email.

And please: keep the code as simple as possible :)

Edit:

I have this one: (which I don't really understand)

```
public void getLocation() {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
}
```

and this one:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    getLocation();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    location_lat = latitude;
    location_long = longitude;
}
```

[Error I'm getting. All three Errors are in line 77](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0Pto.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Android GPS location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498450/how-to-get-android-gps-location)

Comment: But how can I integrate it in my mail? I just add + latitude behind "body of email". It shows the text, but not the number

Comment: do you have the gps coordinates?

Comment: kindly have a look at my original post, it's edited

Comment: u r not getting the coordinates

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission to the manifest(API version<23)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Declare two variables to store the coordinates and one variable of Location

```
Location location;
double latitude;
double longitude;
```

Replace your getLocation() method with this

```
public void getLocation(){
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    if (locationManager != null) {
        try {
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {

        }
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
    }
}
```

After getting coordinates pass this in the email body.

```
...
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "Longitude "+longitude+", Latitude "+latitude);
...
```

Comment: how can I pass them? And If I insert your code, there's so much red :)

Comment: do import import android.location.LocationManager package

Comment: if u r using API 23 or above ask for the location permission dynamically

Comment: for complete code to get the location object(from which u can get the longitude and latitude) follow this answer   https://stackoverflow.com/a/3145655/6029429

Comment: it gives me some strange 'illegal start of expression' and semicolon errors

Comment: share ur screenshot

Comment: bro declare that function in the class not in the onCreate() method.

Comment: and then call it in onCreate() method and also check ur braces ...u are missing one